# i want to use my one table of database for my project in 2 different apps of django python

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

e.g. I have a table of employee in which the Agent can add the employee delete and update.
and I want to show that employee table in the Employee app how can I do it I try but it shows me the error that I can't use that table in 2 apps ... can anyone plz help me with this. if there is a video on youtube then plz share the link

Comment: You can just define the model in one app and import the model in the other app - do you use th Django ORM or do you create tables "manually" using SQL? Please post your code and the complete error message.

Comment: no, i haven't used Django ORM and i had created table manually

Comment: I had already used it but still not working showing same error that I can't use a single table in 2 apps of a project

Comment: Please post the code